# Not able to get correct color value when X,Y are above center of screen

Tags: java, android

Whenever is pass values to x, y which are at center or below the center of screen I get correct pixel color, but when values for x, y are passed which are above the center of screen then I get wrong color values, below is the code I am using

```
private int getColor(int x, int y){

   Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView) mImageView_picture).getDrawable();
   Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();
    Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
    ((ImageView) mImageView_picture).getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
    float[] touchPoint = new float[]{x, y};
    inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
    int xCoord = (int) touchPoint[0];
    int yCoord = (int) touchPoint[1];
    int touchedRGB = bitmap1.getPixel(xCoord,yCoord);
    int redValue = Color.red(touchedRGB);
    int greenValue = Color.green(touchedRGB);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
    int alphaValue = Color.alpha(touchedRGB);
    int colorValue = Color.argb(alphaValue, redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
    return colorValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are possibility that your X & Y coordinates are wrong.
try getting like this.

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
           imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse);
           float[] touchPoint = new float[] {motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY()};
           inverse.mapPoints(touchPoint);
          int  xCoord = Integer.valueOf((int)touchPoint[0]);
          int  yCoord = Integer.valueOf((int)touchPoint[1]);
           Log.v("coordinate",xCoord +" - "+yCoord );
           return true;
       }
   });
```